# Issues with Nested Dictionary and Values Being Overwritten

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologize if this has come up before, but I have not been able to find a thread addressing this issue exactly (just similar issues for non-nested dictionaries)

**Problem:** When I store my variables, everything I stored prior is overwritten

**Background Info and Code:**

I have an object that contains some results as a dictionary for a simulator. I am initializing the dictionary like this:

```
self.ResultsDict = {}


for strat in strategy_list:
    self.ResultsDict[strat] = {}
    
    for sim in range(num_sims):
        self.ResultsDict[strat][sim] = {}
```

For each strategy, I'm running a number of simulations (hence the structure I chose) and for each simulation, parameters are stored.

For example:

```
for strat in strategies:  
  for current_sim in range(num_sims):
     MySimulation.Run(strat)
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric1'] = MySimulation.metric1Results
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric2'] = MySimulation.metric2Results
```

My issue is that when I am storing these results, they override all of the results from the previous sims. At the end I am left with the final simulation's results for every key,value pair for that metric.

I believe this is an issue with referencing or something of the sort, but I am totally lost on how to address this especially within nested dictionaries.

Comment: What is `MySimulation.Run`? Is it returning persisting globals, or is it creating new objects? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: strat in stragtegies are unique ? or can be duplicate ?

Comment: "At the end I am left with the final simulation's results for every key,value pair for that metric." This sounds like your `MySimulation` is reusing and mutating the objects that you then store in that dictionary. A fast fix could be `import copy` and `...['metric1'] = copy.deepcopy(metric1Results)` etc. But the best solution is to change `MySimulation` to avoid mutable results that are reused by subsequent runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to apologize. My code is really complex (because I write code like an ape and am new to OOP) and for the time it was going to take to correctly re-create a functioning example was going to take too long.

I did, however, solve my issue.
This more accurately represents what was happening and so I edited my original post to match this more accurate representation:

```
for strat in strategies:  
  for current_sim in range(num_sims):
     MySimulation.Run(strat)
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric1'] = MySimulation.metric1Results
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric2'] = MySimulation.metric2Results
```

And was solved by doing this:

```
for strat in strategies:  
  for current_sim in range(num_sims):
     MySimulation.Run(strat)
     metric1Results = MySimulation.metric1Results
     metric2Results = MySimulation.metric2Results
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric1'] = metric1Results
     self.ResultsDict[strat][current_sim]['metric2'] = metric2Results
```

Sorry for the confusion, everyone.

Basically what I believe was happening is that by doing the Dict[Key] = Object.Item, every time the simulation ran and the Object.Item was updated for another simulation, it changed all of the values that I had inadvertently mapped the previous dictionary keys to.